# Git ignore only files with the same name as folder

Tags: git

I have this directory structure:

```
app/.bundle/
app/file1.bundle
app/tmp/file2.bundle
app/.gitignore
```

I would like to add an entry in .gitignore that only ignores files that ends with .bundle.

Doing `*.bundle` will also ignore the folder `.bundle`, but I want it checked in along with the contents.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this:

```
*.bundle
!.bundle/
```

This will ignore everything that ends with `.bundle`, *except* a folder that is called `.bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory with a file of the same name
samename/samename then I believe you can add to your .gitignore file:

```
samename/samename
```

Then only the file but not the directory will be ignored. If you only have

```
samename
```

in your .gitignore file then both the directory and the file will be ignored.
In your first version the file with the same name in a different directory will
not be ignored.  Say differentname/samename will not be ignored.  Let me know if I am wrong.